# <asp:updatePanel> inside a user control

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am using a asp:UpdatePanel inside a user control.
This user control is included inside a '.aspx' page.
It is registered and used as follows:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Forms/TestPage.ascx" TagPrefix="ig" TagName="UserControl1" %>

    <asp:Panel ID="ucTestUserCntrl" Visible="false" runat="server">
       <ig:UserControl1 ID="UserControl1" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

<!-- user control code in a diferent page '.ascx' file
-->
<%@ Control Language="C#" Debug="true" CodeFile="TestUserCntrl.ascx.cs"    Inherits="Test_WebUserControl"
AutoEventWireup="true" ClassName="TestUserControl" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Time_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTimeDisplay" Text="00:00:00" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

The user control looks as:

With this I get the error as:
"Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page."

Any suggestion on how to fix this error.

Comment: This isn't classic asp, it's asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You have to  put that user control in  `<ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>`.If you put it outside then  it will give error like you get.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Forms/TestPage.ascx" TagPrefix="ig" TagName="UserControl1" %>



<!-- user control code in a diferent page '.ascx' file
-->
<%@ Control Language="C#" Debug="true" CodeFile="TestUserCntrl.ascx.cs"    Inherits="Test_WebUserControl"
AutoEventWireup="true" ClassName="TestUserControl" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="ucTestUserCntrl" Visible="false" runat="server">
       <ig:UserControl1 ID="UserControl1" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Time_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTimeDisplay" Text="00:00:00" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: content template if this was inside .aspx not a user control